# Looping with laravel

Tags: php, loops, laravel-5

I am confused with this. Here's my code:

```
foreach($request->input('user_id') as $user_id){
            $place = Place::findOrFail($user_id);
            foreach($request->input('username') as $username){
                echo $user_id. ' '. $username .'<br>';
                continue;
            }
        }
```

The result of this is:
**1 User1 

1 User2 

1 User3 

3 User1 

3 User2 

3 User3 

5 User1 

5 User2 

5 User3**

*Result that I want is:*

**1 User1 

3 User2 

5 User3**

Comment: this behaviour is completely normal. You'll have to change your form logic so that you have a way to link the user_ids to usernames. At the moment they are only independant inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will show duplicate entries because ther is loop inside loop. Traverse through only one loop only

```
<?php
$user_ids = $request->input('user_id');
$user_names = $request->input('username');
foreach($user_ids as $key=>$value){            
            echo $value. ' '. $user_names[$key] .'<br>';                
        }
    }
```

But make sure you have same numbers of user_id and usersname for this

Comment: what the `$user_names[$key]` does?

Comment: @Jonjie It will return username